# Let and memory allocation

Tags: ios, swift

I was searching for a Objective-C `define` equivalent in Swift and a lot of people told me to use `let`.

I need a lot of constants in one class and I need to create a lot of objects from this class so I think that I will waste too much memory using `let` instead of `define`

Am I wrong? Maybe `let` works in a different way.
Is there a way to achieve this without wasting memory?

Comment: `#define` should not be used for constants.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally, `let` should waste a lot *less* memory (and other resources) than `#define`. Because imagine you have

```
#define SOME_PATH [[[@"/" stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"foo"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bar"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"buz"]
```

Everywhere, you'll use `SOME_PATH`, it will *redo* the calculation and create a new `NSString *` for that (plus some temporary ones).

By using

```
let SOME_PATH = "foo".stringByAppendingPathComponent("bar").stringByAppendingPathComponent("buz")
```

it will do the calculation to build the string exactly *once* and it will only need *one chunk* of memory (whilst building the string there'll be some temporary objects created that are discarded quickly).

So you can use your `let` constant *for free* as often as you want. The `#define`d macro will have costs every time you use it.

Remember you can use `let` in global scope. So `let` doesn't just work within functions or classes, you can also define a global constant with `let`.

Comment: "to build the string exactly once" and lazily (if global), so if you never use the value, it will never be calculated and will never be allocated in the first place.